# C programming why wont my code print the correct output with nested struct arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, printing, struct, nested

I completely ran out of ideas as to why one piece of my program isn't printing out properly. This program has an Array of structs called Customers which has a nested array of structs called groceries.

Both index's (customers in the array) Print there info fine. Grocery struct index 0 of customer 1 is fine. Grocery struct index 1 gives me C garbage. If anyone can help out I'd really appreciate it.

**input.txt**: ( first number is the number of customers, second number is the groceries for 1st customer. third number is groceries for 2nd customer)

```
2
John Brown
3
Cabbage 1.50 2.5
Cucumbers 1.00 3.0
Tomatoes 2.99 1.5
Mary Winters
4
Squash 1.48 2.5
Zucchini 1.99 3.5
Watercress 1.29 2.5
Tomatoes 2.99 3.0
```

My code output is to a file called "**invoices.txt**"

```c
/* Preprocessor commands */
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define VEG_COL 50

/* Defining structs / nested structs */
typedef struct veg{
    char vegName[15];
    float weight, unitPrice;
} vegitable; 

/* ---------------------------------------------- */

typedef struct cx{
    char fName[15],lName[15];
    int numGroceries;
    vegitable groceries[VEG_COL];
} customer;

/* ---------------------------------------------- */




  /* Prototypes*/

    int numCust(FILE*);
    void createCustomer(FILE*,customer *cx, int);
    void createGroceryList(FILE*,vegitable *veg);
    void printInvoice(FILE*wPtr,customer cx);


    /* Main function */
    int main () {

    FILE *ptr, *wPtr;
    int numCustomers, i;
        ptr = fopen("input.txt","r");
        wPtr = fopen("invoices.txt","w");

        numCustomers = numCust(ptr);
        customer customerList[numCustomers];

        for(i = 0; i < numCustomers; i++) {
            createCustomer(ptr,&(customerList[i]), i);  
        }

        for(i = 0; i < numCustomers; i++) {
            printInvoice(wPtr,customerList[i]);
    }
        fclose(ptr);
        fclose(wPtr);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
    }

    /* ---------------------------------------------- 
        Function that reads file for number of customers */

    int numCust(FILE*ptr) {
        int num;
        fscanf(ptr, "%d", &num);    
    return num;

    }

    /* ---------------------------------------------- 
        Function that reads file and creates customer */

    void createCustomer(FILE*ptr,customer *cx, int i) {
        char tempF[15],tempL[15],k;

            fscanf(ptr,"%s%s", tempF,tempL);
            strcpy(cx->fName,tempF);
            strcpy(cx->lName,tempL);
            fscanf(ptr,"%d", &(cx->numGroceries));

                for(k=0;k<cx[i].numGroceries;k++) {
                    createGroceryList(ptr,&(cx[i].groceries[k]));
                }
    }

    /* ---------------------------------------------- 
        Function that reads file and creates customers grocery list */

    void createGroceryList(FILE*ptr,vegitable *veg){
        char temp[15];

        fscanf(ptr,"%s%f%f", temp, &(veg->unitPrice), &(veg->weight));
        strcpy(veg->vegName,temp);

    }

    /* ---------------------------------------------- 
        Function that prints an output file for the invoice */

    void printInvoice(FILE*wPtr,customer cx) {
        int k, numItems = 0;
        float total = 0;

            fprintf(wPtr, "Customer Name: %s %s\n\n", cx.fName,cx.lName);
                for(k = 0; k < cx.numGroceries; k++) {
                    fprintf(wPtr, "%s \t%.1f @ %.2f\t$%.2f\n\n", cx.groceries[k].vegName,cx.groceries[k].unitPrice,cx.groceries[k].weight,cx.groceries[k].unitPrice * cx.groceries[k].weight);  
                    total += (cx.groceries[k].unitPrice * cx.groceries[k].weight);
                    numItems++;
                }
            fprintf(wPtr, "---------------------------------------------\n\n");
            fprintf(wPtr, "Total\t\t\t\t$%.2f\n\n",total);
            fprintf(wPtr, "%d items bought\n\n\n\n",numItems);

        }
```

Comment: Compile your code with warnings enabled, your compiler should shout at you and tell you to fix your code.

Comment: Try with valgrind, memset to 0 your struct could help

Comment: @Ôrel this is Windows code, look at the useless `system("pause");` thing that apparently they use because the `cmd.exe` is also useless.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you ignore the return value of `fscanf()` in various locations in your code.

The first one to point out is

```
fscanf(ptr,"%d", &(cx->numGroceries));
```

in case a read failure occurs, for example because the data does not match the format, you still use `cx->numGroceries` which is uninitialized, leading to ... ??? Undefined Behavior.

You also wrote this function in a wierd manner

```
void createCustomer(FILE*ptr,customer *cx, int i) {
    char tempF[15],tempL[15],k;

        fscanf(ptr,"%s%s", tempF,tempL);
        strcpy(cx->fName,tempF);
        strcpy(cx->lName,tempL);
        fscanf(ptr,"%d", &(cx->numGroceries));

            for(k=0;k<cx[i].numGroceries;k++) {
                createGroceryList(ptr,&(cx[i].groceries[k]));
                /*                         ^ ?? */
            }
}
```

Either use the index notation to access the array of `cx`'s via the pointer, or use the `->` operator to dereference the pointer to the current `cx` which is effectively equivalent to `cx[0]` using the `.` operator.

Here is a version of your code with all the issues mentioned above already fixed

```
/* Preprocessor commands */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define VEG_COL 50

/* Defining structs / nested structs */
typedef struct veg
{
    char vegName[15];
    float weight, unitPrice;
} vegitable;

/* ---------------------------------------------- */

typedef struct cx
{
    char fName[15], lName[15];
    int numGroceries;
    vegitable groceries[VEG_COL];
} customer;

/* ---------------------------------------------- */


/* Prototypes*/

int numCust(FILE*);
void createCustomer(FILE*, customer *cx);
void createGroceryList(FILE*, vegitable *veg);
void printInvoice(FILE*wPtr, customer cx);


/* Main function */
int main ()
{

    FILE *ptr, *wPtr;
    int numCustomers, i;

    ptr = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (ptr == NULL)
        return -1;
    wPtr = fopen("invoices.txt", "w");
    if (wPtr == NULL)
    {
        fclose(ptr);
        return -1;
    }
    numCustomers = numCust(ptr);

    customer customerList[numCustomers];

    for (i = 0 ; i < numCustomers ; i++)
        createCustomer(ptr, &customerList[i]);

    for(i = 0; i < numCustomers; i++)
        printInvoice(wPtr, customerList[i]);

    fclose(ptr);
    fclose(wPtr);

    return 0;
}

/* ----------------------------------------------
    Function that reads file for number of customers */

int numCust(FILE*ptr)
{
    int num;
    if (fscanf(ptr, "%d", &num) != 1)
        return 1;
    return num;

}

/* ----------------------------------------------
    Function that reads file and creates customer */

void createCustomer(FILE*ptr, customer *cx)
{
    char tempF[15], tempL[15];
    int k;
    /* You could use cx->fName[0], instead*/
    cx[0].fName[0] = '\0'; /* in case `fscanf()' fails */
    cx[0].lName[0] = '\0';
    if (fscanf(ptr, "%s%s", cx[0].fName, cx[0].lName) != 2)
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: failed to read first and last name.\n");
    if (fscanf(ptr, "%d", &(cx[0].numGroceries)) != 1)
        cx[0].numGroceries = 0;

    for (k = 0 ; k < cx[0].numGroceries ; k++)
        createGroceryList(ptr, &cx[0].groceries[k]);
}

/* ----------------------------------------------
    Function that reads file and creates customers grocery list */

void createGroceryList(FILE *ptr, vegitable *veg)
{
    veg->vegName[0] = '\0';
    if (fscanf(ptr, "%14s%f%f", veg->vegName, &(veg->unitPrice), &(veg->weight)) != 3)
        fprintf(stderr, "file format error\n");
}

/* ----------------------------------------------
    Function that prints an output file for the invoice */

void printInvoice(FILE*wPtr, customer cx)
{
    int k, numItems = 0;
    float total = 0;

    fprintf(wPtr, "Customer Name: %s %s\n\n", cx.fName, cx.lName);
    for(k = 0; k < cx.numGroceries; k++)
    {
        fprintf(wPtr, "%s \t%.1f @ %.2f\t$%.2f\n\n",
            cx.groceries[k].vegName,
            cx.groceries[k].unitPrice,
            cx.groceries[k].weight,
            cx.groceries[k].unitPrice *
            cx.groceries[k].weight
        );
        total += (cx.groceries[k].unitPrice * cx.groceries[k].weight);
        numItems++;
    }
    fprintf(wPtr, "---------------------------------------------\n\n");
    fprintf(wPtr, "Total\t\t\t\t$%.2f\n\n", total);
    fprintf(wPtr, "%d items bought\n\n\n\n", numItems);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`fopen` result should be tested to avoid `segfault`
Think about dynamically allocate the memory

A quick fix

```
int main () {                                                                  

    FILE *ptr, *wPtr;                                                          
    int numCustomers, i;                                                       
    ptr = fopen("input.txt","r");                                              
    wPtr = fopen("invoices.txt","w");                                          
    /* should be tested */                                                     

    numCustomers = numCust(ptr);                                               
    customer customerList[numCustomers];                                       
    memset(customerList, 0, numCustomers * sizeof(customer));                  

    for(i = 0; i < numCustomers; i++) {                                        
        createCustomer(ptr,&(customerList[i]));                                
    }                                                                          

    for(i = 0; i < numCustomers; i++) {                                        
        printInvoice(wPtr,customerList[i]);                                    
    }                                                                          
    fclose(ptr);                                                               
    fclose(wPtr);                                                              
    return 0;                                                                  
}

void createCustomer(FILE*ptr,customer *cx) {                                   
    char tempF[15],tempL[15],k;                                                

    fscanf(ptr,"%s%s", tempF,tempL);                                           
    strcpy(cx->fName,tempF);                                                   
    strcpy(cx->lName,tempL);                                                   
    fscanf(ptr,"%d", &(cx->numGroceries));                                     

    for(k=0;k<cx->numGroceries;k++) {                                          
        createGroceryList(ptr,&(cx->groceries[k]));                            
    }                                                                          
}
```

Give this output

```
aurel@vm-fat:~$ cat invoices.txt 
Customer Name: John Brown

Cabbage         1.5 @ 2.50      $3.75

Cucumbers       1.0 @ 3.00      $3.00

Tomatoes        3.0 @ 1.50      $4.49

---------------------------------------------

Total                           $11.24

3 items bought



Customer Name: Mary Winters

Squash  1.5 @ 2.50      $3.70

Zucchini        2.0 @ 3.50      $6.97

Watercress      1.3 @ 2.50      $3.22

Tomatoes        3.0 @ 3.00      $8.97

---------------------------------------------

Total                           $22.86

4 items bought
```